# addSubview() in viewDidLoad() not working

Tags: xcode, swift

I use following code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let testView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568))
    testView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    self.view.addSubview(testView)

}
```

And not happens when view did load.

But it nice working in IBAction

Why?

Answer (score 1):

first try to use swift syntax CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:320, height:568) and show us the way you create the ViewController.

Make sure the viewDidLoad() method gets called coz this code works for me.

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
var window: UIWindow?
let viewController  = ViewController()

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    let tabBarController = UITabBarController()
    let controllers = [self.viewController]
    tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    self.window!.backgroundColor    = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.window!.rootViewController = tabBarController
    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let testView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:320, height:568))
    testView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    self.view.addSubview(testView)
}
```

Comment: Have you assigned this class to the storyboard viewController?

Comment: Method called, swift syntax not help. ViewController emdeded into TabBarController

Comment: im using storyboards + nibs, (like https://www.silviogutierrez.com/blog/combining-storyboards-and-xibs-xcode/)